Solve for $x$ in $y=x\operatorname{arccot}(x)$
I was wondering if it's possible to move $x$ to the LHS in the following simple equation?
$$y=x\operatorname{arccot}(x)$$
I know $\operatorname{arccot}$ could be rewritten as:
$$y=x\arctan(1/x)$$
$$y/x=\arctan(1/x)$$
$$\tan(y/x)=(1/x)$$
$$x=\tan(y/x)^{-1}$$
Still can't isolate $x$ on LHS. I'm only interested in the real part visualized below where ${[x>0,y>0]}$.


There really isn't a way . Most functions don't have good closed form inverse, even when they are invertible.

You can iterate the last equality to obtain an infinite nested form of the inverse.

Are you looking for a series or integral representation?

@Gary I see, but it gets messy since it doesn't give a clean line, thank you for the suggestion though.

@ТymaGaidash Any works, both are fine I think.

Look at the edit for large values of $y$

Hint
You can have good approximations of the inverse of $$y=x \cot ^{-1}(x)$$ straing from the Taylor series of the arctangent function
$$\cot ^{-1}(x)=\frac \pi 2-\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{ n}} {2n+1 }\,x^{2n+1}\tag 1$$ Truncate to some order and use power series reversion to obtain (I only print the first terms because the coefficients start to be messy)
$$x=\frac{2 y}{\pi }+\frac{8 y^2}{\pi ^3}+\frac{64 y^3}{\pi
   ^5}-\frac{32 \left(\pi ^2-60\right) y^4}{3 \pi ^7}-\frac{256
   \left(\pi ^2-28\right) y^5}{\pi ^9}+O\left(y^6\right)\tag2$$
Now, to take into account the asymptotic behaviour of $y$, take a bit more terms and transform the series into an $[n,n]$ Padé approximant $P_n$ of it to obtain
$$x=\frac{\sum_{k=0}^n a_k\,y^k}{1+\sum_{k=1}^n b_k\,y^k}$$
With the very few terms given above, a very simple one is
$$x_{(2)} \sim P_2=\frac {\frac{2 }{\pi }y+\frac{2 \left(\pi ^2-24\right) }{3 \pi
   ^3}y^2 } {1+\frac{\left(\pi ^2-36\right) }{3 \pi ^2}y-\frac{4 \left(\pi
   ^2-12\right) }{3 \pi ^4}y^2 }$$
Since we know the coefficient of $(1)$, we know all coefficients of $(2)$ using the explicit formula for the $n^{\text{th}}$ term as given by Morse and Feshbach in year $1953$ and so, we can generate any $P_n$ of our choice for more and more accuracy.
If we compute
$$y- x_{(2)} \cot ^{-1}(x_{(2)})=-\frac{8 y^3}{\pi ^4}$$
For sure, this is a bit unsufficient for large values of $y$ but it will improve a lot increasing $n$.
Edit
Fot the case where $y > \frac 34$ a good approximation is
$$x_*=t-\frac{3}{10 t}-\frac{3}{280 t^3}-\frac{1}{6000
   t^5}+O\left(\frac{1}{t^7}\right)\qquad \text{with} \qquad t=\frac{1}{ \sqrt{3(1-y)}}$$
$$y-x_* \cot ^{-1}(x_*)=\frac{39609 }{21560000}(1-y)^5$$

This is super interesting, Thank you!
